# Php cookies not setting in whole website

Tags: php

On my site, I set cookies expire time until 30 days. This is working for me in the main directory, but not on a sub-directory,

**this.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30; 
setcookie ("user","David", $expire);
//this works and outputs the cookies value
?> 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["user"];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**files/this.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["user"];
//error:cookie is empty
?>
</body>
?>
```

Comment: Don't set cookies after you begin outputting data.  Cookies are response headers and must be sent before data is sent.  That may not solve your immediate problem, but is something you should do.

Comment: Please read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add **/** in set cookies, adding a **/** can solve your problem, this means cookies are available in the entire site.

**this might help you**

```
<?php
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30; 
setcookie ("user","David", $expire,"/");
//this works and outputs the cookies value
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cookies should be set before browser output as they are part of the HTTP header.

See: http://php.net/cookies

If you're wanting immediate storage and recall, perhaps `$_SESSION` would be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

When you set cookies server-side the information is transmitted in HTTP headers. The [manual](http://php.net/setcookie) warns about this:

> `setcookie()` defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the
>   HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any
>   output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This
>   requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output,
>   including `<html>` and `<head>` tags as well as any whitespace.

If you are not getting an appropriate warning from PHP, please tweak your error reporting settings until you do.